# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable. This is my error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am trying to create a Time-Series model for forecasting few values. But whenever I am trying to read the file, I am getting an error.
The line which is in bold and italic is generating error.
This is my code :

```
import warnings
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
matplotlib.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'

***df = pd.read_csv["forecasting.csv", ","]***
t1 = df.loc[df['Technology'] == 't_1']
```

Comment: When post code block formatting like bold, itallic, etc. does not work. And always post full traceback you get.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Use  round brackets - ( and ), not square brackets [ and ], i.e.

```
df = pd.read_csv("forecasting.csv", ",")
```